# How to change "Choose File" on file type input using BootForm

Tags: php, laravel-5

Please help me to change text "Choose File "on file type input button???
If possible, how do I change its shape ???
I am coding on laravel blade using BootForm.

```
{!! BootForm::file('Upload File', 'upload_file')->helpBlock('Please upload a file to verify your submit.') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think about changing choose file

just hide choose file and change the label for that file input, this code may help you

{!! Form::label('upload_file', 'UPLOAD',['class'=>'btn btn-md btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::file('upload_file',['style'=>'visibility:hidden']) !!}